# Angular Build Breaks with provider.ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular

I recently updated my Angular project to versions below:

Taken from my package.json:

```
"@angular/animations": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
"@angular/common": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/core": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.18",
"@angular/forms": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/http": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/router": "^6.1.9",
```

A prod build has all of the router links breaking. Console reads

> "TypeError: provider.ngOnDestroy is not a function". This can be found in my core bundle "core.umd.js" in callProviderLifecycles().

If I go to a page by typing the link in the url, it loads as expected. But when I click a `[routerLink]` the error occurs.

I cannot duplicate this on a local ng serve, but only happens when the prod bundle is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up removing my node_modules and running npm install fresh. The error went away.